# save Hash to a column (type: text) in database by serialization, why is it saved YAML

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, serialization, hash, yaml

We are trying to serialize an attribute called differences in order to save the value of this attribute as a Hash into database. The type of differences is text. it used to be saved as Hash in the database. But recently we found out it is saved yaml. is there any way to prevent it saving as yaml?

```
  Class A < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :bs
    serialize :differences

    def diff(other)
      b_diffs = {}
      bs.zip(other.bs).each do |a,b|
       b_diffs.merge!(:bs => a.diff?(b)
      end
    end

    def diff_against_last_a
      last_a = ....
      self.differences = last_a.diff(self)
    end
  end
```

Any suggestion?

EDIT: 
 my problem is i can't retrieve differences as Hash.

Interestingly, when i check on console, it is saved as yaml, and retrieved as yaml. and then i rerun the the method diff(other) and save the result to differeces, it shows as Hash and i can retrieve Hash. But it doesn;t work this way when running on my app.

I think the problem here is the serialized data are no longer returned Hash.

UPDATE:
So i found out under the development environment, there is such a problem. But in production and staging (we use heroku), it practises fine. so We'll consider it ok then.

Comment: `yaml` is default serialization in rails. What is the issue here? If you try to retrieve `differences` in rails environment it will still be a `Hash`.

Comment: hmm. when I retrieve differenecs, it becomes a string not Hash any more. What i don't understand is it used to retrieve as for example, {:a => {:b => {attr_1: 2}} } and now it is like  "--\n :a \n  :b\n  :attr_1\n  2\n" after retrieving. not sure why. what i need is hash.

Comment: cause you have not defined serialize type. I am updating my answer please check

Comment: I did, before i posted this, it didn't work. it was working without defining its serialize type.

Comment: try serialize as I have updated in my answer, then save a new hash and try to retrieve it. It should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to my comment, here is the official description:

> If you have an attribute that needs to be saved to the database as an
>   object, and retrieved as the same object, then specify the name of
>   that attribute using this method and it will be handled automatically.
>   The serialization is done through YAML. If class_name is specified,
>   the serialized object must be of that class on retrieval or
>   SerializationTypeMismatch will be raised.

source: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class

In layman's terms "When Rails serializes a hash to save in the db, all it does is convert it to YAML so that it can be stored as a string."

As the last line of official description reads, you have define the class of retrieval. `Hash` in your case. So declare serialize like this:

```
 serialize :differences, Hash
```

Comment: Incase your console is open where you are trying to retrieve the hash, restart it after making changes. Its important!

Comment: Interestingly, when i check on console, it is saved as yaml, and retrieved as yaml. and then i rerun the the method diff(other) and save the result to differeces, it shows as Hash and i can retrieve Hash. But it doesn;t work this way when running on my app. Tried with defining Hash. Console was restarted i'm sure.

Comment: restart the server and the console. If its working one place it should work other place too, logically speaking

Comment: I'm sorry, it still doesn't work. We are using ruby on rails 3.2.13. would it be a version problem?

Comment: logically speaking, it should be working in this way i reckon.

Comment: It cannot be a version problem. Something else is wrong. Please check.

Comment: @user2775888 try last thing. Go to console, retrieve any object for `A`. Say `a = A.first`. Now set difference as: `a.differences = {"key"=>"val"}` and save `a`. And try to retrieve it. If its working fine, there is something wrong with your method `last_a.diff(self)`.

Comment: oh yes. in that way it is working fine. Great, thanks! I'll look into that method :).

Comment: one more question, in console, i retrieved two object of A, say a1 a2. i run a1.differences = a1.diff(a2), a1.save. it works well, got Hash, saved Hash, retrieved as Hash. may be the method is alright?

Comment: In cases where there is the issue, instead of saving `a1.diff(a2)` directly to `a1.differences`, verify what class `a1.diff(a2)` is? You can do that by: `a = a1.diff(a2)` followed by `a.class`. As per my understanding, in cases where there is issue, it wont return `Hash`

Comment: it returns Hash... isn't this strange?

Comment: how to make query/where clause to serialize hash column?
for ex, I want to get record that matched some value in specific key in hash.